# Can I create a symlink or similar that returns a random file from a set every time?

Tags: macos, unix, filesystems, symbolic-link

Say I have files `foo-a.wav`, `foo-b.wav` and `foo-c.wav` on disk.

I have a piece of software whose interface allows me to enter the name of a single sound file; every time a certain feature of that software is activated it loads that file and plays it.

I want to play a random sound every time this feature is activated.

Is there some feature of the Unix filesystem that will let a file access for `foo.wav` return any of `foo-a.wav`, `foo-b.wav` or `foo-c.wav` at random?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The closest thing you could do would be to write a program to serve up a unix domain socket and change the content it serves each time a client connects.

Comment: ...or a crontab entry to change it every minute, depending if it's allowable to have the same file repeat.

Comment: Or, a crontab entry that checks the file's access time every minute, and changes the symlink when it's been accessed.